# NoMethodError in Users#show undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been stuck with this issue for sometime now. I'm building a blog with users and articles. At this point, users and articles have been created and signup, login and logout functionalities have been added.

Here is my code:

user_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to Alphablog, #{@user.username}"
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Your account has been successfully updated"
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def require_same_user
    if current_user != @user
      flash[:danger] = "You can only edit your own account"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

The problem seems to be in: users/show.html.erb, where the username in @user.username doesn't seem to be working. Not sure why. Relooked at all my code but to no avail..

```
<h1 align="center">Welcome to <%= @user.username %>'s page</h1>
<h4 align="center"><%= @user.username %>'s articles</h4>
<%= render 'articles/article', obj: @user.articles %>
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`@user` is `nil` in your Show view. You're not calling `set_user` or otherwise populating that variable, so there is no way for it to be set. You probably want to include `:show` in the list of actions you're running `set_user` for:

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

should become

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful!